# Jquery next() does not get next element

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
<h1><a href="#" class="link">Click here</a></h1>
<div class="acitem"></div>
<div class="acitem2"></div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a.link').click(function() {
            var element = $(this).next();

            alert(element.attr('class'));
        });

    });
</script>
```

When I have the 'click here' link wrapped inside an H1 tag, the alert call returns 'undefined', but if I remove the H1 tag from the link, then the alert call correctly returns 'acitem'.  With the H1 tags in place, I have also tried:

```
$(this).nextUntil('.acitem')
```

But this still returns 'undefined'.

I am a bit confused as to how the next() function works in JQuery. Anyone know why the next function works correctly only if I remove the H1 tags from the link?  Is there something I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`next()` works for siblings, in your structure, `<a>` is the only child `<h1>` has, so calling `next()` would technically returns nothing as `<a>` is the only son of `<h1>`. Hence why it works if you remove `<h1>`

Quoting the docs:
`Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.`

http://api.jquery.com/next/

`nextUntil()` gets a set of elements starting from the selector up to but excluding the selector given as argument, quoting the docs: `Get all following siblings of each element up to but not including the element matched by the selector, DOM node, or jQuery object passed.`

http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/

About your query, you can call `.parent()` prior to calling `next()` to make sure you are getting the sibling of its parent (i.e. his uncle)

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a.link').click(function() {
            var element = $(this).parent().next();

            alert(element.attr('class'));
        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

@andreas is right about `.next` and `.nextUntil`.  His solution with `.parent` is good too.

Another thing you can do is use the Next Adjacent selector ( http://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-Selector/ )

```
var element = $('h1 + div');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/LMr5E/